# Power automate error: Authentication Failed

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

So here is my flow : [image]

And the error I get that I absolutely do not understand : `"body": "Authentication Failed. Please make sure x-api-key header is present and has a valid value."`
If anyone has a lead on how I can solve this I take it.

Comment: Just to double check. That Ré-obtenir la tâche action. Is that by any chance a Send an HTTP request action which you renamed? If so, could you share which headers you used in the configuration of this action?

Comment: @Expiscornovus look at the icon, it looks to be Sharepoint.  You can't change that icon.

Comment: @Skin, I was referring to the Send an HTTP request to SharePoint action, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/connectors/sharepointonline/#send-an-http-request-to-sharepoint and the title of an action can be renamed. As best practice I don't do that to make troubleshooting a bit easier though :P

Comment: @Expiscornovus No it's not a Send an HTTP request it is a Get Element action. To troubleshoot there is possibility to click on the litte ? to see what action it really is (if you renamed it)